Launch4j | "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment." when opening .exe, that is a .jre file converted to .exe
I run the file with command prompt
Command:
file.exe

Output:
This application requires a Java Runtime Environment.

Is this error due to the .exe using the wrong JRE path?
I've tried the below variations:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path\

The below showcases that I do have a working JRE, and I provided the correct location of the JRE.
Command 1:
java --version

Output 1:
java 22.0.1 2024-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing)

Command 2:
where java

Output 2 :
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path\java.exe


Would really appreciate ANY help!

@AndrewYim I revised the question, anything else I can improve on? ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

It would be nice to have the problem in the body text, preferably with more detail as to the specifics of your problem. [ask] has some more details on this.

Seems like you have both Java 22 and Java 8 (32 bit) installed. Maybe you should remove the Java 8 installation?

Incidentally, 3rd party installers haven't been needed since Java 9 That operation essentially bought you nothing, since it's still looking for the JRE. It might as well have been a jar. jpackage will bundle the runtime

Its not the JRE which got converted to exe.
It is trying to find java runtime which is is installed in the system, its not getting that and giving this issue.
Try the below 2 points -

Check in the the system settings, if your JAVA_HOME is set properly and Path is mentioned till <JAVA_HOME>\bin folder.
Go to CMD and type PATH. It will show you the details.
From your output it looks fine to me.

Do you have JDK installed as exe or Configured as Portable JDK in your system.


If your JDK is not installed, try to install that as "exe" file, it will solve your problem.
